# How to submit non-blocking job in Gearman?

Tags: message-queue, gearman, python-gearman

I want to use `result = gearman_client.submit_job("reverse_task", "Hello World!", wait_until_complete=False)` to submit a non-blocking job to Gearman Job Server. However, `result.state` is always `'CREATED'`, and `result.complete` is always `False`. If I change `wait_until_complete` to `True`, then everything goes right. That's so wired. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

As python-gearman described [here](http://pythonhosted.org/gearman/client.html?highlight=wait_until_jobs_completed#gearman.client.GearmanClient.submit_multiple_jobs), you should use `gearman_client.wait_until_jobs_completed([result])` to wait until all jobs completed, rather than checking `result.complete` in a while loop.